# Multiply columns of different sheets in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need to multiply the no.of grants into the expected attrition rate based on dates. In image 3 i have the rates and now for image 2, i need to multiply the rates in image based on the date. Im new to power bi and i'm not able to work it out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data and your desired output in the report.

Comment: I have added couple of images and the output in image 3

Comment: Where from that Attrition rate comes? Logic?

Comment: It is inputted. i have one sheet with rates and have another sheet with dates. I need the rates based on sheet 2 in the sheet 1 with dates alone.